# Can't find self.tableview after accidental delete

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios4

I accidentally deleted my firstviewcontroller.m file which is for a view that has a tableview. I then re-created my .m file the best I can remember and thought I had it all correct.

I'm now getting an error on the line

[self.tableview refresh];

saying self.tableview isn't found.

I can't seem to figure out what I missed. I don't want to overwhelm you guys with code so I'll try to just post the pertinent part.

`#import "FirstViewController.h"`
`#import "Shared.h"`
`#import "Message.h"`

`@implementation FirstViewController`

`-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {`
    `static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";`
    `UITableViewCell *cell= [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];`
    `if (cell == nil) {`
        `cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];`
   `}`
    `Message *msg = [[Shared sharedInstance].messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];`
    `NSString *authorName = msg.authorName;`
    `NSString *cellValue = authorName;`
    `cell.textLabel.text = cellValue;`
    `return cell;`
`}`

`-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {`

```
`return [[Shared sharedInstance].messages count];`
```

`}`

`-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {`

```
`[self.tableView reloadData];`
```

`}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tableView is a property of UITableViewController. Double-check that you inherited FirstViewController from a UITableViewController, but not from UIViewController.

Comment: That fixed that error but created another.  Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UITableViewController loadView] loaded the "FirstView" nib but didn't get a UITableView.'

Comment: I'll repost as a new question